# What is the admin url in a Django template (and where is a list of all system urls)?

Tags: django

I was looking at some Django examples and I've noticed that you can call certain urls with a variable like this `<a href="{% url auth_login %}">Log in</a></li>`. How would I call the admin page with the same idea?

A more general question: is there a list of pre-defined url variables that Django uses? And how are they defined (how can they be overridden)? Some other ones I know that exist are `auth_logout` and `auth_password_change`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It generally depends on urls you write in your **urls.py**.

Relevant Django documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/

When you add django.contrib.admin, you add its urls by using `(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),`, which you can view here: https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/admin/sites.py#L217

Comment: +1, also for the admin urls in templates use {% url admin:index %} (replace index with the name defined in the urls)